# Onclick function does not work when doing function call

Tags: html, button

I have a button that does not call the function when the button is clicked. The `onclick` function can display an alert window but does not run the function call.

```
...
   <fieldset>
        <legend>Billing Information</legend>
        <label for="name2">Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name2" name="full_name"><br>
        <label for="zip2">Zip code:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="zip2" name="zip_code">
   </fieldset>
   <button type="button" onclick="clear()">Verify</button>
...
<script>
    function clear() {
        document.getElementById("name1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("zip1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("name2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("zip2").value = "";
    }
...
</script>
```

So this works:

```
   <button type="button" onclick="alert("Hello")">Verify</button>
```

But the function `clear` does not work. I don't see why this doesn't work.

Comment: If your `<button>` is in a form then it becomes `type='submit'` by default. `FormElement.onsubmit = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }` if you are using AJAX, or change the `<button type`. So, my guess, even with your lack of code, is that your Browser which reloads your webpage when the submit occurs, remembers the fields when you submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a picky one.

The problem here is that the word `clear` is in the scope of `document.clear`. So, that method is being requested instead of yours.

The solution there would be to use a different word than `clear` to run that function.

Another solution would be not to use inline event handlers, but to define the listener all in code using javascript.

Here's some documentation on `document.clear()`. It's in the process of being removed from the Web Standards.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear